# Want to exclude a kubectl job from helm installation

Tags: hook, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

want to exclude a kubectl job from helm installation and helm upgrade.
Checked helm hook but didn't find any suitable tag for that. Can I create a custom tag for helm hook.
Is there any way where I can run my job with helm command apart from install or upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a variable while running your install/upgrade helm.

By doing it you can use this variable and create a condition inside your hook before running it.

To pass this variable you need to use the option `--set` while running `helm` command.

`helm upgrade . --set initSetup=false`

This variable can be tested inside your hook as it's made on common helm charts as on [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/templates/initialization-configmap.yaml) one.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, can u tell me how can I use the variable that we give in helm command in template.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/templates/svc-read.yaml) is a better example

Answer (score 0):

Adding on Mark Watney's answer, here's how I've done it.

I start by wrapping the job with an `if` checking if value `runScript` exists or is true :

```yaml
{{- if .Values.runScript }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: script
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: script
          image: "{{ .Values.script.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.script.image.tag }}"
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - echo "Running Script"; npm run script
[...]
{{- end }}
```

Then, I can either add in my `values.yml`:

```
runScript: true
```

Or when calling `helm upgrade ...`, I can add `--set runScript=true` at the end, and the job will get created. Either way, it won't.